# dataframe sort values by multiple sub columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data with multi-index columns in a pandas dataframe format that I would like to sort by values in multiple sub-columns. First `('pdb_info',h_index')` and then `('pdb_info','dis')`

[image: image1]

I succeeded in my jupyter environment, but in the linux environment I get the error message like:

> 'value error : cannot handle a non-unique multi-index'

[image: image 2]

Comment: Are you using the same version of pandas in both environments (jupyter, linux)?

Comment: 1.0 version in jupyter environment, 1.12 version in linux environment..

Comment: So there must have been a change in the method from 1.0 to 1.12. Have you checked the documentation of 1.12  (isn't it 1.1.2)? Another option would be to sort by one tuple first such as ('pdb_info', 'h_index') and then ('pdb_info', 'dis').